# Value of type _ cannot convert to specified type Set<> Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm trying to create a set of random exercises.  I have made my struct Hashable and Equatable following the tutorial here https://medium.com/@JoyceMatos/hashable-protocols-in-swift-baf0cabeaebd and that is working fine so it's ready to be put in a Set<>.

When I use an Array to collect the workout exercises, as per below, it works fine.  But when I switch to a Set<> I get an error "cannot convert value of type [_] to specified type 'Set'.  What is it about 'Sets' that mean you can't map in the same way as an Array?

```
func generateWorkout() {
    let allPossibleExercises = masterExerciseArray
    let numberOfExercisesKey = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)+3)

//error triggers on the line below if I switch [WorkoutExercise]
//for Set<WorkoutExercise> (which conforms to Hashable/Equatable

let workoutSet : [WorkoutExercise] = (1...numberOfExercisesKey).map { _ in
        let randomKey = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allPossibleExercises.count)))

return WorkoutExerciseGenerator( name: allPossibleExercises[randomKey].name,
 maxReps: allPossibleExercises[randomKey].maxReps).generate()
    }
    print (workoutSet)
}
```

There is an answer here with a similar error message [Cannot convert value of type '[_]' to specified type 'Array'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451973/cannot-convert-value-of-type-to-specified-type-array) but my array wouldn't be empty as in this example so I don't think this is the same root cause?

**UPDATE : for anyone having the same problem, you can use Array but then simply convert the Array to a Set afterwards if the correct elements are Hashable/Equatable**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If creating the array works create the array and then make the `Set` from the array. If all involved objects conform to `Hashable` this is supposed to work.

```
func generateWorkout() {
    let allPossibleExercises = masterExerciseArray
    let numberOfExercisesKey = Int(arc4random_uniform(4)+3)

    let workoutArray : [WorkoutExercise] = (1...numberOfExercisesKey).map { _ in
        let randomKey = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allPossibleExercises.count)))

        return WorkoutExerciseGenerator( name: allPossibleExercises[randomKey].name,
                                      maxReps: allPossibleExercises[randomKey].maxReps).generate()
    }
    let workoutSet = Set(workoutArray)
    print (workoutSet)
}
```

Comment: Both elements are Hashable/Equatable - i'm not getting any errors about that.  The error line is shown under the m in map if that helps

Comment: No, only `WorkoutExercise` must conform to `Hashable`